# Plotting alignment issues with plotting raster list of raster objects and multiple polygons together

Tags: raster, r, polygon, plot

I am very new to R and am trying to plot one object from a raster list with multiple polygons (boundary shapefiles) together in one plot. When I resize the plot window, however, the alignment of the layers change. I am assuming that their alignment needs to be fixed somehow, but I don't know how to do this.

I've included all code for importing raster data (NSIDC sea ice concentration rasters) and shapefiles (one is a management boundary and the other is a digitization of land masses). I want to remove (mask) all land pixels and pixels outside of the management boundary so that I can focus on only the ice/water pixels within the management boundary.

```
# set up raster -------------------------------------------
pixel <- 25000 #pixel dimension in meters for both x and y
xMin <- -3837500 #From NSIDC: ulxmap -3837500
xMax <- xMin + (pixel*304)
yMax <- 5837500 #From NSIDC: ulymap 5837500
yMin <- yMax - (pixel*448)
r <- raster(nrow=448, ncol=304, xmn=xMin, xmx=xMax, ymn=yMin, ymx=yMax)
projection(r) <- '+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273     +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs'

# bin converting fx 
bin_raster <- function(ymd){
filename <- paste("data/","nt_", ymd,"_v1.1_n.bin", sep="")
con <- file(filename, 'rb')
x <- readBin(con, "raw", 300)
x <- readBin(con,"int", size=1, signed=FALSE, 150000)
close(con)
x[x==251] <- 1
x[x>251] <- 0 # set all non-ice pixels to 0% ice cover
x[x<251] <- x[x<251]/250 #scale ice cover to 1
rr <- setValues(r, x) # place result in raster

#change file names to just the date
geoTiffFile<- paste('geoTiffs/', ymd,'.tif',sep='')
rr <- as.list(rr)
}

# create raster list

# extract file names for loop
files <- list.files("data", pattern=".bin$") 

# string manipulation
dates <- str_sub(files, 4, -12) 

# create an empty list 
raster_list <- rep(NA, length(dates))

# loop over all the files and fill the list
for(i in seq_along(dates)){
raster_list[i] <-   bin_raster(dates[[i]])
}

# rename rasters with dates
list_names <- str_sub(dates, 0, -5)
names(raster_list) <- list_names



# Clip to the management area shapefile -----------------------------
# Import shapefile
boundary <- readOGR("filepath/Management_area.shp")
plot(boundary)
# Change projection of shapefile to match raster list (i.e. polar stereographic)
proj4string(boundary)
boundary_proj <- spTransform(boundary, crs('+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70    +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs'))
proj4string(boundary_proj)
plot(boundary_proj)

# Crop and mask list to the shapefile
raster_list <- lapply(X=raster_list, FUN=crop, y=boundary_proj)

# mask pixels outside of management area
for(i in 1:length(raster_list)){
raster_list[[i]] <- mask(raster_list[[i]], boundary_proj)
}

# look at resulting raster
plot(raster_list[[4]])
plot(boundary_proj, add = TRUE)



# Clip to land ---------------------------------------------
# Import shapefile and check projection
land_mask <- readOGR("filepath/boundary_minusland.shp")
plot(land_mask)
plot(boundary_proj, add = TRUE)
proj4string(land_mask) # at this point the plotting looks good

# Crop and mask list to the shapefile
raster_list <- lapply(X=raster_list, FUN=crop, y=land_mask)

# mask pixels outside of DS management area
for(i in 1:length(raster_list)){
raster_list[[i]] <- mask(raster_list[[i]], land_mask)
}

# look at resulting raster
plot(raster_list$'19930209')
plot(boundary_proj, add = TRUE)
plot(max_ice_extent, add = TRUE)
#This final plot looks fine until you start playing around with resizing the plot window,
#then the alignment changes so that the land shapefile (land_mask) does not align with the raster pixels
```

Comment: Can't run your code without your data, but I have seen things misalign after resizing plot windows, and the solution is: a) don't resize your plot window and b) if you resize your plot window then re-run the plotting code which *should* fix the alignment. If you can make a *really* simple reproducible example (which should only take half a dozen lines) this might get looked at in more detail.

Comment: I guess I should have asked this more clearly. I'm not so worried about how the plot looks as much as I am concerned that this is influencing my actual dataset - i.e. is "raster_list" being clipped/masked properly if the alignment seems off when it's plotted?

Comment: I'd trust the spatial operations more than the plotting, because I have seen plot alignment problems in the past. But for your example, its impossible to tell without your data or maybe you could include some images of what's going on? But if the alignment looks good before resizing, and if you resize **and then re-plot** and it still looks good, then its fine.

Comment: You're totally right. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This seems to be a bug. This question [has also been asked on Stackoverflow over 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213453/overlay-raster-plot-using-plot-add-t-leads-to-arbitrary-misalignment-of-fin) and there isn't yet a solution other than using `image()`.